# How to get two decimal digits when it has only one

Tags: c#, .net

I have a decimal with value "2.2", what i need is "2.20".

I have tried

```
String.Format("0:0.00",decimalVar);
```

and

```
decimal.Round(decimalVar,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

and

```
Math.Round(decimalVar,2)
```

But they are all returning the original "2.2" value. There are plenty of answers for this question but they are all about "How to limit digits to two if they are more than two".

I need to show two digits when there is only one digit.

Comment: can you show the code printing the result of String.Format("0:0.00",decimalVar); because it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple typo, your first line should be:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", decimalVar)
```

Note the braces. Alternatively, you can use

```
decimalVar.ToString("0.00")
```

**Why rounding doesn't fix your problem:**

Mathematically, `2.2` is exactly the same as `2.20`, so `Round` won't change anything. The *only* thing that matters here is how you *format* the mathematical value into a decimal *string*. Thus, `String.Format` and `ToString(someFormatString)` are the correct choices here.

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
String.Format("0:0.00",decimalVar);
```

to:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}",decimalVar);
```

a [working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) of your example

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ToString`

```
decimalVar.ToString("0.00")
```

or `String.Format`

```
string.Format("{0:0.00}",decimalVar));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want 2 digits after decimal point in the *string representation*, just *format it out* (`F2` in your case):

```
  Decimal value = 2.2M;
  String result = value.ToString("F2"); // 2.20
```

Other possible formats you may find useful:

```
 0.00
 0.#0
 #.#0
```

Note, that *Math* says that `2.2 == 2.20` that's why `Round()` is not a way out.

Answer (score 0):

use below code snap

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    format.format(decimal);
```